# How to handle nested arrays within Solr?

Tags: solr

I am currently trying to store my chat conversation data into Solr that looks this:

```json
{
    "id":"1",
    "chat_id": "Chat: *************6B2E47",
    "messages": [
        {
            "party": "Victim",
            "content": "[Chat started]",
            "timestamp": "08.05.2023 03:34:30 UTC"
        },
        {
            "party": "Victim",
            "content": "give me proof that you have comptomised us",
            "timestamp": "08.05.2023 03:35:18 UTC"
        }
     ]
}
```

Now I have the following in my managed-schema.xml

```xml
<fieldType name="nested" class="solr.NestPathField" />

<!-- Define the fields for the document -->
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

<field name="chat_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<!-- Define the nested field with explicit sub-fields -->
<field name="messages" type="nested" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true">
    <field name="party" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="timestamp" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
</field>
```

After that running and creating an new core it prompts me the following error when importing an same-like json file that I listed above

The error is :

```
ERROR: [doc=1/messages#0] unknown field 'party'
```

How do I fix this to import same exact data-structure like I listed above ?